# how to make a list of strings into a regular list?

Tags: python, string, list, gspread

in a loop `for`, I make several api requests and at the output I get links from json(there are different numbers), then I convert them to strings (because there are some `None` values, and I need to write them to google sheets)

as a result on the output of **print(value)** I have:

`['"https://example"']`

`['"https://example"']`

`['null']`

each has a string type

i need to get list `value = [link1, link2, none]`

```
cell_values = value
for i, val in enumerate(cell_values):  
   cell_list[i].value = val  
   worksheet.update_cells(cell_list)
```

I think I've tried everything I can.

if you do not convert this to a list, then either each value is written to one cell and overwritten, or each letter is written separately to the range

Comment: At first sight I'd say that your code up there does not change your cell_values -list at all. You just insert the same value in same place in the list it used to have.

Comment: it changes but overwrites the cell with the following value
['"https://example"'] > ['"https://example"'] > [null]

and I'm already confused how to make it write all this in a column

If I understand correctly, I need to write the result of the loop into a list, but I can't create a list from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

found a bug in my code and now everything works

I made a list variable inside the loop, **but I had to make a list variable before the loop**, and in the loop already write strings to the variable

simple mistake,
the question is closed

Comment: Well done for finding the solution to your own question! If you can, please edit your question to show the difference in code. That is always much more telling than explaining it in words :)